# Can't understand the answer of this problem

Tags: combinatorics

> You have a password which contains 5 letters and 1 digit at the end of the password. How many passwords contains the letter 'A' three times and the letter 'B' two times and ends with even number?"

The answer is

> $$5.{\binom{5}{2}}$$

I understand that 5 stands for the 5 even digits, but I can't figure out why the number of combinations for the letter part of the password is this binom coef ?

Cleary if I enumerate all the possible values

AAABB,
AABAB
...

I find out that they're exacty 10, but I want to know why this is represented as Combiation ? I guess I don't undestand the true meaning of Combinations. Any help would be appretiated. Thanks

Comment: Once we **choose** in which $2$ slots the $2$ B's go, we have determined the alphabetic part of the password.

Comment: Or you can visualise the problem this way:
There are 5 slots to be filled in and u have 3 A's and 2 B's to do that so you can do that in $\frac{5!}{3!*2!}$ ways which turns out to be ${\binom{5}{2}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first 5 is equal to $5\choose1$ because of the 5 even unit digits, 1 is chosen.

Let's look at the answer differently.

We are sorting five but there is a repetition of 3 A's and 2 B's

$\frac{5!}{3!\cdot 2!}$ = 10 is what you say for this.

There is no reason why you need to simplify it further but it is equal to $5\choose2$ by definition.

$5\choose2$ = $\frac{5!}{(5-2)!\cdot 2!}$

Just some advice with counting methods in general. It is best to work them out and see if your answer is equal to theirs than to look at the solution and change the way you see the problem

Answer (score 0):

It is a permutation of 5 letters (elements), divided by the amount of elements, which belong to the identical groups: ${5 \choose 2}=\frac{5!}{3!\cdot 2!}$ You do not distingquish between the three A´s respectively the two B´s. Thus you have to divide 5! by 3! and 2!.